Deploying a New Lambda Function with AWS CodeBuild and AWS CodeCommit but Lambda function not created
I am trying to deploy an AWS Lambda function using AWS CodeCommit and AWS CodeBuild. The pipeline works well—all are in the right order, and the build is successful—but it doesn't create the Lambda according to my code; an error appears during the deploy phase. And also, when creating a new Lambda function, the requirements.txt should contain Python requirements, so those requirements need to be installed as well.
buildspec.yml :
​version: 0.2

env:
  variables:
    S3_BUCKET: deployment

phases:
  install:
    runtime-versions:
      python: 3.11
    commands:
      - pip install aws-sam-cli
  build:
    commands:
      - sam build
  post_build:
    commands:
      - sam package --s3-bucket $S3_BUCKET --output-template-file packaged.yaml
artifacts:
  files:
    - packaged.yaml

template.yml :

​AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Resources:
  MyLambdaFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: lambda_handler.lambda_handler
      Runtime: python3.11
      CodeUri: s3://deployment/packaged.yaml
      MemorySize: 1024
      Timeout: 100
      Environment:
        Variables:
          PARAM1: "value1"
      Policies:
        - AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole


Error :


you have to explicitly install from requirements.txt like "pip install -r requirements.txt", put that under install or build phase before "sam build"

Still same issue.
It shows following line in logs : The resource AWS::Serverless::Function 'MyLambdaFunction' has specified S3 location for CodeUri. It will not be built and SAM CLI does not support invoking it locally.

If you provide a function's Amazon S3 URI or FunctionCode, you must reference a valid Lambda deployment package.
As you are using SAM, please refer to the below document to upload files from local path for building
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/deploy-upload-local-files.html
